# Different datatype from endpoint

Tags: laravel, api, ssl, laravel-4, postman

created a basic Api Rest service in Laravel 4.2 (the project was created in this version), and local responses me corresponding datatype (Int), but when execute endpoint from online server, receive different datatype(String) to local(Int), appreciate someone who knows the reason of this.

Local example
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ7DC.png)

Online CentOs Server example
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Knsd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... are you using MySQL?

Comment: i do, i'm sending data from MySQL query